# No AndroidManifest.xml found - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, mvvmcross

This is very interesting scenario which i have been facing from last few days.I have a Xamarin project which is using MvvmCross and few 3rd party libraries like RestSharp.
Few days back when i got project code and open it i found it abnormal that project property folder has more then 1 manifest files.When i tried to run project the visual studio was not picking up android manifest file.
I search on internet about this and got few clues.

- Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) in its root directory.

i am posting my file structure image for reference.i have checked my .csproj file it has following code

```
 <AndroidManifest>Properties\TurboViewerarmAndroidManifest.xml</AndroidManifest>
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Properties\TurboViewerarmAndroidManifest.xml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
```

As far as my concern if i change the manifest file name to AndroidManifest.xml the project runs fine but the problem occurs when i try to change name of other manifest file to AndroidManifest.xml because we can not have many files with same name in single folder.But for this project all the manifest files will be in same folder but project will not run without changing their name to AndroidManifest.xml.Its like a deadlock.

[image: The file structure]

[image: Folder with all manifest files]

As i am new to visual studio and xamarin so i might be missing some point that probably will make everything clear.

Comment: As Luke points out and you are aware, you should only have one manifest per project. If you have dependencies on other projects, they should also have one manifest each and at build time perform a process known as manifest merging which will merge elements based on a ruleset. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html This process is the same in native Android as well.

Comment: I would look for a build script the previous might've setup as these different manifests look specific to cpu architectures. Perhaps they swapped manifests per architecture or created an app for each ABI.

Answer (score 0):

> Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) in its root directory.

That's your issue - your Android manifest file is called `TurboViewerarmAndroidManifest.xml`. Rename it to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you haven't read my full question.
As far as my concern if i change the manifest file name to AndroidManifest.xml the project runs fine but the problem occurs when i try to change name of other manifest file to AndroidManifest.xml because we can not have many files with same name in single folder.But for this project all the manifest files will be in same folder but project will not run without changing their name to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I did read it, but I must have misunderstood. Why do you need more than one Android manifest? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: because the project is based on other projects and each have its own manifest file.

Comment: The other projects (assuming they are Android apps) need to have their own AndroidManifest.xml files in their own directories, not in `TurboViewerarm`'s directory.

Comment: i got this project as it is. it has many parts which i am not familiar of and i can not change them because it will ripple effect others.But this project was working on the laptop of previous dev.it should work on my system. u must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to do very same for a white-label app. Visual Studio ignores the AndroidManifest setting so you cannot rename the file (at the moment). This is an already known issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=31306

Even a pre-build process doesn't work since it always throws an error that the manifest file is missing (but it's there).

My solution for now: rename the manifest before building the project manually.

Answer (score 0):

Restart my Visual Studio helps.